# Simple NTP question

Tags: cisco, ntp

Setting up NTP on a cisco 3560 so clients can be all on the same time. The switch it only used at layer 2. Outside of having a management VLAN for SSH, there isn't currently any config for anything else.

I try to have windows 10 1607 clients sync time through the control panel, but it fails to sync. Thanks for your time.

Following is the switch config:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2534 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 15:11:59 UTC Wed Aug 15 2018 by avnadmin
! NVRAM config last updated at 14:53:13 UTC Wed Aug 15 2018 by avnadmin
!
version 15.0
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname SWITCH
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
username admin privilege 15 secret 5 REDACTED
no aaa new-model
system mtu routing 1500
ip domain-name IT
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/24
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/25
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/26
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/27
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/28
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/29
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/30
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/31
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/32
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/33
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/34
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/35
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/36
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/37
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/38
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/39
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/40
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/41
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/42
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/43
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/44
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/45
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/46
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/47
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/48
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/49
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/50
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/51
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/52
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.0.254 255.255.255.0
!
ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
!
!
vstack
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
ntp source Vlan1
ntp master
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `ntp server SERVERNAME`

If your switch isn't synchronised, it won't allow downstream clients to synchronise either.

Check with `show ntp status`

You can use public servers such as `ntp server pool.ntp.org`; if you don't want to configure your switches with DNS you'll have to look up the IP address of the upstream time servers.

Be aware that using unverified upstream servers might present security issues, especially in timestamps for logs and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the help! the client is synced. However the time on the bottom of the computer hasn't changed. Will it do that on the next sync time, or am I confused?

Comment: It can take a few minutes for a client to sync. Additionally, do you have the Windows machines set to sync specifically to the switch (by IP?)? If it's just set to the default it's syncing to Windows' time source, not your switch.
Can the clients actually reach the switch's address? 

I would also try removing the 'ntp master' statement.

Comment: I do have them internet time pointing to the IP. I’m gonna let it alone over the weekend to see if it makes the change. I’ll keep you posted! Thanks.